# Как найти detached коммиты?

Tags: git

Однажды откатился на какой-то безымянный коммит. И, не создавая новую ветку, сделал несколько новых коммитов.

После чего лазил через SourceTree и "случайно" перешёл на другую ветку. После чего `Detached HEAD from 1f231656aabcd2...` бесследно пропал.

Все решения ведут к

```
git reflog --all
```

Ищи там свой коммит, переходи туда (checkout), создавай новую ветку и мерж, или сразу мерж. Но я не могу найти там своих последних коммитов. Всё старьё.

Comment: `git fsck --lost-found`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

в выводе `git reflog` ищите строку "moving from".

---

пример сообщения о переходе от несвязанного ни с каким указателем (веткой или тегом) коммита к ветке `master`:

```
$ git reflog
...
2217ae2 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 70c48300c538de67deb020df43b036728c133187 to master
...
```

если теперь посмотреть

```
$ git log 70c48300
```

то видна вся последовательность коммитов, по цепочке связанных с искомым.