# Исчезла ветка "no branch" и все изменения вместе с ней

Tags: git, tortoise-git

Каким то образом делал коммиты без ветки. Хотя я вроде вообще ничего не трогал.

Захотел чтобы изменения делались в мастере.
Нажал Swith/Checkout, в branche выбрал master, нажал ок.
Проект перешёл на последний коммит в ветке мастер, а ветка "no branch" пропала.

Что делать не понимаю.
Как вернуть все изменения?

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486272/178576), связанный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/232455/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не запускали сборку мусора(git gc), то все хорошо и изменения можно вернуть. Выполните `git reflog show` и пройдитесь по истории ваших изменений, еще не все потеряно)

Comment: Спасибо! Всё вернулось.

Comment: @Man2020rgb если вам это помогло, то, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за ответ)